# Защищённая децентрализованная сеть

Tags: c#, сеть, blockchain

Доброго времени суток.
Пытаюсь писать диплом на тему "Разработка приложения многофакторной аутентификации для защищённой децентрализованной сети" на С#.

Скажите пожалуйста какие есть готовые решения для развертывания децентрализованной сети в локальной сети? Так как писать приложение без самой децентрализованной сети не представляется возможности, так как нужно понимание как подключиться к этой сети. 
Саму структуру децентрализованной сети знаю.

Заранее спасибо.

В идеале децентрализованная сеть должна хранить данные(файлы). Соответственно после авторизации в приложении вы должны увидеть свои файлы.

Comment: Готовое решение вам здесь никто не даст. У вас есть какие либо наработки по этому вопросу? Какую задачу должна будет выполнять данная сеть? Распишите подробнее данный вопрос пожалуйста

Comment: TOR & etc. -- достаточно *готовое решение для развертывания децентрализованной сети* ?

Comment: В сети имеются 4-5 компьютеров. Развернуть децентрализованную сеть для хранения данных. Соответственно 1 компьютер - мастер у которого все адреса файлов. Остальные обращаются к нему для получения и вывода этих файлов в приложении.

Comment: Такая себе децентрализация. Ваш "мастер" является центральным узлом.

Comment: Стоит начать с общения клиентов по UDP протоколу используя  широковещательный адрес. А дальше разрабатывать протокол и логику поведения системы.